# To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2008

I am new to Qt. I have an application given by a vendor, I am trying to build my application,

I get the  following errors, I have spent hours to solve this error,
none of the solutions i have referred seems to solve my prob

#### moc_mainwindow.cpp

```
e:\installed softwares\msvc2008\vc\include\xsens\xsstring.h(268) : warning C4996: 'mbstowcs': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using mbstowcs_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        E:\Installed Softwares\MSVC2008\VC\INCLUDE\stdlib.h(499) : see declaration of 'mbstowcs'
e:\installed softwares\msvc2008\vc\include\xsens\xsstring.h(270) : warning C4996: 'mbstowcs': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using mbstowcs_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        E:\Installed Softwares\MSVC2008\VC\INCLUDE\stdlib.h(499) : see declaration of 'mbstowcs'
e:\installed softwares\msvc2008\vc\include\xsens\xsstring.h(311) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        E:\Installed Softwares\MSVC2008\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(366) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
e:\installed softwares\msvc2008\vc\include\xsens\xsexception.h(48) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        E:\Installed Softwares\MSVC2008\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(366) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
moc_myxda.cpp
sktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\awindamonitor" -I"." -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008" -D_MSC_VER=1500 -DWIN32 ..\awindamonitor\measurementstarter.h -o debug\moc_measurementstarter.cpp
    e:\MoCap\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\bin\rcc.exe -name awindamonitor ..\awindamonitor\awindamonitor.qrc -o debug\qrc_awindamonitor.cpp
    rc -D_DEBUG -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -fo debug\icon.res ..\awindamonitor\icon.rc
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -Zi -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include" -I"E:\MoCap\MTW SDK 4.1.5\GUI\awindamonitor\..\..\Win32\include" -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\awindamonitor" -I"." -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_mainwindow.obj.5008.546.jom
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -Zi -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include" -I"E:\MoCap\MTW SDK 4.1.5\GUI\awindamonitor\..\..\Win32\include" -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\awindamonitor" -I"." -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_myxda.obj.5008.3261.jom
connectedmtwdata.cpp
measurementstarter.cpp
e:\installed softwares\msvc2008\vc\include\xsens\xsstring.h(268) : warning C4996: 'mbstowcs': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using mbstowcs_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        E:\Installed Softwares\MSVC2008\VC\INCLUDE\stdlib.h(499) : see declaration of 'mbstowcs'
e:\installed softwares\msvc2008\vc\include\xsens\xsstring.h(270) : warning C4996: 'mbstowcs': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using mbstowcs_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        E:\Installed Softwares\MSVC2008\VC\INCLUDE\stdlib.h(499) : see declaration of 'mbstowcs'
e:\installed softwares\msvc2008\vc\include\xsens\xsstring.h(311) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        E:\Installed Softwares\MSVC2008\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(366) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
Generating Code...
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -Zi -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include" -I"E:\MoCap\MTW SDK 4.1.5\GUI\awindamonitor\..\..\Win32\include" -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\awindamonitor" -I"." -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_measurementstarter.obj.5008.3261.jom
myxda.cpp
serialkey.cpp
Generating Code...
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -Zi -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
The system cannot find the path specified.
MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include" -I"E:\MoCap\MTW SDK 4.1.5\GUI\awindamonitor\..\..\Win32\include" -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\awindamonitor" -I"." -I"..\..\..\QT\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\qrc_awindamonitor.obj.5008.4134.jom
qrc_awindamonitor.cpp
moc_measurementstarter.cpp
e:\installed softwares\msvc2008\vc\include\xsens\xsstring.h(268) : warning C4996: 'mbstowcs': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using mbstowcs_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        E:\Installed Softwares\MSVC2008\VC\INCLUDE\stdlib.h(499) : see declaration of 'mbstowcs'
e:\installed softwares\msvc2008\vc\include\xsens\xsstring.h(270) : warning C4996: 'mbstowcs': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using mbstowcs_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        E:\Installed Softwares\MSVC2008\VC\INCLUDE\stdlib.h(499) : see declaration of 'mbstowcs'
e:\installed softwares\msvc2008\vc\include\xsens\xsstring.h(311) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        E:\Installed Softwares\MSVC2008\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(366) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
main.cpp
mainwindow.cpp
e:\installed softwares\msvc2008\vc\include\xsens\xsstring.h(268) : warning C4996: 'mbstowcs': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using mbstowcs_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        E:\Installed Softwares\MSVC2008\VC\INCLUDE\stdlib.h(499) : see declaration of 'mbstowcs'
e:\installed softwares\msvc2008\vc\include\xsens\xsstring.h(270) : warning C4996: 'mbstowcs': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using mbstowcs_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        E:\Installed Softwares\MSVC2008\VC\INCLUDE\stdlib.h(499) : see declaration of 'mbstowcs'
e:\installed softwares\msvc2008\vc\include\xsens\xsstring.h(311) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        E:\Installed Softwares\MSVC2008\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(366) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
e:\installed softwares\msvc2008\vc\include\xsens\xsexception.h(48) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        E:\Installed Softwares\MSVC2008\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(366) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
```

Comment: These are warnings, not errors, and thus can be ignored (at least as the cause of your build failing). Your real error is in the post-build script or a custom build step (`The system cannot find the path specified.`)

Comment: Do you know difference between errors and warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Add `-D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to your compiler flags to avoid the warnings in 3rd party library code such as Qt.

If code code you control is the source of the warnings, fix the problem.  The warning tells you exactly what to do.

Replace calls to `sprintf` with calls to `sprintf_s` etc.

Comment: Microsoft has decided that `sprintf` is unsafe, and that programmer should use `sprintf_s` instead. `sprintf` is still part of the ISO C standard, and like almost any function, it can be used safely or unsafely. Using `sprintf` is not *necessarily* a problem. The 2011 ISO C standard adds an *optional* set of bounds-checking interfaces, including `sprintf_s`, but using `sprintf_s` can make your code less portable; all conforming C compilers support `sprintf`.

Comment: How can I do that? I know how to do that in Visual Studio, but not in the QT Creator? Should I write something into project file? I suppose I should use the flags only for MSVC compiler. I have more kits in the project (MSVC, MinGW, GCC).